# How to sort a map by two values?

Tags: go

I am trying to sort a map by two of its values. First by the timestamp and then by the nonce. In other words, I need to be able to iterate and print the map with the smallest timestamp first, followed by the nonce value. Like this:

```
    "tx1": Transaction{Value:10, Nonce:1, Timestamp:1563543005},
    "tx2": Transaction{Value:20, Nonce:2, Timestamp:1563543005},
    "tx6": Transaction{Value:60, Nonce:2, Timestamp:1563543005},
    "tx5": Transaction{Value:50, Nonce:4, Timestamp:1563543005},
    "tx7": Transaction{Value:70, Nonce:1, Timestamp:1563543006},
    "tx3": Transaction{Value:30, Nonce:3, Timestamp:1563543006},
    "tx4": Transaction{Value:40, Nonce:4, Timestamp:1563543006},
```

Here is my code:

https://play.golang.org/p/hXo5clCrlU1

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Transaction struct {
    Value         uint64                        `json:"value"`
    Nonce         uint64                        `json:"nonce"`
    Timestamp     int64                         `json:"timestamp"`
}

func main() {
    // To create a map as input
    memPool := map[string]Transaction {
        "tx1": Transaction{Value:10, Nonce:1, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx2": Transaction{Value:20, Nonce:2, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx3": Transaction{Value:30, Nonce:3, Timestamp:1563543006},
        "tx4": Transaction{Value:40, Nonce:4, Timestamp:1563543006},
        "tx5": Transaction{Value:50, Nonce:4, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx6": Transaction{Value:60, Nonce:2, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx7": Transaction{Value:70, Nonce:1, Timestamp:1563543006},
    }


    keys := make([]string, 0, len(memPool))
        for key := range memPool {
            keys = append(keys, key)
        }

        sort.Slice(keys, func(i, j int) bool { return memPool[keys[i]].Timestamp > memPool[keys[j]].Timestamp })


    for _, v := range keys {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println("")

    keys2 := make([]string, 0, len(memPool))
        for key2 := range memPool {
            keys2 = append(keys2, key2)
        }

    sort.Slice(keys2, func(i, j int) bool { return memPool[keys2[i]].Nonce > memPool[keys2[j]].Nonce })

    for _, v := range keys2 {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```

Current output:

```
tx7
tx3
tx4
tx1
tx2
tx5
tx6

tx4
tx5
tx3
tx6
tx2
tx7
tx1
```

Desired output:

```
tx1
tx2
tx6
tx5
tx7
tx3
tx4
```

Comment: You want it sorted once, so sort it once, into one slice of keys, by whatever logic you want it sorted by. Not sure what exactly you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are not sure what I am having trouble with? I am trying to get the desired output and can't get it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sorting two separate times when it appears you want to sort once. So, sort once, using all of the logic that you want to use to sort your values, once.

```
sort.Slice(keys, func(i, j int) bool {
    if memPool[keys[i]].Timestamp == memPool[keys[j]].Timestamp {
        if memPool[keys[i]].Nonce == memPool[keys[j]].Nonce {
            return memPool[keys[i]].Value < memPool[keys[j]].Value
        }
        return memPool[keys[i]].Nonce < memPool[keys[j]].Nonce
    }
    return memPool[keys[i]].Timestamp < memPool[keys[j]].Timestamp
})
```

Working example: https://play.golang.org/p/GERCSchEtOf

Answer (score 2):

Compare both search criteria at once:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Transaction struct {
    Value         uint64                        `json:"value"`
    Nonce         uint64                        `json:"nonce"`
    Timestamp     int64                         `json:"timestamp"`
}

func main() {
    // To create a map as input
    memPool := map[string]Transaction {
        "tx1": Transaction{Value:10, Nonce:1, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx2": Transaction{Value:20, Nonce:2, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx3": Transaction{Value:30, Nonce:3, Timestamp:1563543006},
        "tx4": Transaction{Value:40, Nonce:4, Timestamp:1563543006},
        "tx5": Transaction{Value:50, Nonce:4, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx6": Transaction{Value:60, Nonce:2, Timestamp:1563543005},
        "tx7": Transaction{Value:70, Nonce:1, Timestamp:1563543006},
    }

    keys := make([]string, 0, len(memPool))
    for key := range memPool {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }

    sort.Slice(keys, func(i, j int) bool {
        ti, tj := memPool[keys[i]], memPool[keys[j]]
        if ti.Timestamp == tj.Timestamp {
            return ti.Nonce < tj.Nonce
        }
        return ti.Timestamp < tj.Timestamp
    })

    for _, key := range keys {
        fmt.Println(memPool[key])
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oFDG9Fti2JV

Output:

```
{10 1 1563543005}
{60 2 1563543005}
{20 2 1563543005}
{50 4 1563543005}
{70 1 1563543006}
{30 3 1563543006}
{40 4 1563543006}
```

Observe how the `less func(i, j int) bool` argument to `sort.Slice` is implemented: since it has to sort by timestamps first and nonces second, the only case where it has to consider nonces is when timestamps are equal (as otherwise they already define ordering of the elements being compared).